# Taxonomy and custom content in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, taxonomy

I'm trying to do something fairly simple: I would like to be able to create a game site which would act as a database. When clicking on a game name the page would display:

- Game name and description + other details.
- The game developer name (which would like to the game developer page which would have its own set of details)
- Game publisher name (which would like to the game publisher page which would also have its own set of details.)
- Latest news related to this game
- Latest media related to this game

All of this in a tabbed interface like for example:
http://www.gamespot.com/the-elder-scrolls-online/ (you can click on review / news / images / etc in the menu)

This seems a very simple taxonomy/custom content set-up of any CMS to be honest but I have been struggling to find the logic behind it.

My questions are:

- If wordpress is the right tool for such a site, is it as simple a taxonomy/content type?
- If wordpress isn't the right tool, which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short:**

Yes, WP is good choice.

**Long:**

Wordpress is very powerfull software and you can easly change it and adapt it. As you mentioned you can use custom taxonomy (how many you want) and/or custom post types. It's pretty easy to implement.

Fantastic community will help you with problems and huge amount of ready made plugins. Lots of them works out of the box :)

Please remember about security - wordpress is secure as long as you do not have password admin/admin ;) Be sure to have login name other than obvious one (admin, administrator, etc) and remember to change table prefixes in database. It is good also to hide your wp version, and your servers data :)

Yes, wordpress is good choice :)